# How to parse xml with repeated tags in List?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

There is an xml with repeated tags, something like this:

```
<abc:Body>
   <abc:AssyData>
     <abc:Order>1</abc:Order>
     <abc:Name>A</abc:Name>
   </abc:AssyData>
   <abc:AssyData>
     <abc:Order>2</abc:Order>
     <abc:Name>B</abc:Name>
   </abc:AssyData>
   <abc:AssyData>
     <abc:Order>3</abc:Order>
     <abc:Name>C</abc:Name>
   </abc:AssyData>
</abc:Body>
```

Need to parse each value of abc:Order and abc:Name and put it in a List. At the moment my parser only gets the first value. Here is the code:

```
String order = null;
String name = null;
List<String> orders = new ArrayList<String>()
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>()
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
     dbf.setFeature(XML.Constants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
     DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = db.parse(new File(IDOC));//IDOC это мой XML на диске
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("abc:Body");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
       Node node = list.item(temp);
       if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element element = (Element) node;
          orders.add(element.getElementsByTagName("abc:Order").item(0).getTextContext());
          names.add(element.getElementsByTagName("abc:Name").item(0).getTextContext());
       }
     }
} catch ......
System out println(orders);
System out println(names);
```

output:

```
List<String> orders = [1]
List<String> names = [A]
```

And you need to get all the values ​​of all elements by tag and write them to the sheets, what would be:

```
List<String> orders = [1,2,3]
List<String> names = [A,B,C]
```

Please help (java ee 5)

method getElementByTagName does not exist) I used getElementsByTagName, it did not help

orders.add(element.getElementsByTagName("abc:Order").item(0).getTextContext());
names.add(element.getElementsByTagName("abc:Name").item(0).getTextContext());

Comment: method getElementByTagName does not exist) I used getElementsByTagName, it did not help

Comment: "_Comments in code blocks must be written in English, otherwise they're just noise;_" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/11107541

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values of the repeated tags, you need to loop through the NodeList of the "AssyData" elements instead of just getting the first element. You can modify your code as follows:

```
String order = null;
String name = null;
List<String> orders = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
     dbf.setFeature(XML.Constants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
     DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = db.parse(new File(IDOC));//IDOC это мой XML на диске
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("abc:AssyData");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {
       Node node = list.item(temp);
       if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element element = (Element) node;
          orders.add(element.getElementsByTagName("abc:Order").item(0).getTextContent());
          names.add(element.getElementsByTagName("abc:Name").item(0).getTextContent());
       }
     }
} catch ......
System.out.println(orders);
System.out.println(names);
```

In this modified code, we use getElementsByTagName instead of getElementByTagName to get all the elements with the specified tag name. Then, we loop through the NodeList of "AssyData" elements and add the values of "abc:Order" and "abc:Name" to their respective lists.

This should result in the desired output:

```
List<String> orders = [1, 2, 3]
List<String> names = [A, B, C]
```

Comment: @starball => Which comment? Can you please mention that comment?

Comment: Dear @starball, Pardon! That's a Russian Comment meaning "IDOC is my XML on disk".